# CodeIgniter equivalents of ASP.NET MVC Master pages and content areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, codeigniter, templates

I used PHP years ago but have since been developing in C#/VB.Net.

In ASP.Net MVC 2, you can provide a master page which defines content areas eg:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Overshare | <?=$Title?></title>              
        <ContentArea name="Head"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ContentArea name="Body"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your view would then have something like:

```
<Content name="Head">
    <!-- Some Head Content -->
</Content>
<Content name="Body">
    <h1>Some Body Here</h1>
</Content>
```

I don't seem to be able to emulate the same functionality with Code Igniter. The options seem to be:

- manually pre-set some associative array of variables (eg in the controller) and then simply substitute the values into a template file - This is a lot of code to repeat in each view and doesn't belong in the controller. It also means it's a real pain to put large bodies of html into one of the `ContentAreas` - It's either string concatenation or something equally nasty with almost no chance of HTML intellisense in any IDE.
- Use a templating library - I haven't found one which doesn't fundamentally work as described above

Now, I haven't used CodeIgniter before and am about to start a large PHP project so want to make sure it's the correct tool before actually starting work. Am I missing something obvious or is this templating functionality difficult to replicate?

Edit: Libraries tested:

- [Phil Sturgeon's Template Library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Phil_Sturgeon%27s_Template_Library/)
- [CI Smarty](https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty)
- [PHXView](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PHXView_View_Engine/)

Comment: Which template libraries for CI have you looked at? This is not really difficult to do, but it's true that CI does not have any kind of template system - it's pretty much up to you to find one or write your own.

Comment: @Wesley I've edited the Q to include Libraries I've tried. There was 1 more I can't find again. Would I be better using a different framework? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating 3 files which represented the following

OpenHeader:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <Head Stuff/>
```

OpenBody:

```
    </head>
    <body>
        <html>
            <Templating Stuff>
```

Close:

```
            </Templating Stuff>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then modified my views to include these three at the appropriate time.

It's inelegant but flexible and powerful so it'll do for now - especially since I can pass varuables eg Page title into the files during the include if I use the CodeIgniter view engine to retrieve them

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good idea of how your pages are to be built then you can write a set of functions to deal with it either in a MY_Controller.php file or in a library.

So you could have a routine which calls

$this->mypagetemplates();

Which calls data out of a class's properties eg $this->page->title;

I split my data as I create it into

$this->page->head,
$this->page->header,
$this->page->content,
$this->page->aside
$this->page->footer

Which corresponds with the HTML5 sections we use in 90% of our projects

My $this->mypagetemplates() function (or method if you prefer) can take a number of arguments and calls various views as a result eg:

$contentview = 'shop/products';
$asideview   = 'shop/basket';

Which, if populated, are then called thus

```
If ($asideview) {
    $this->load->view($asideview, $this->page->aside);
}
```

Overall Though, I'd say don't design your biggest ever project on a framework that us new to you.  Play around first.

Comment: @ AlunR Thanks for replying - "Play around first." - That's exactly what I'm doing. Cheers for the suggestions - I'll do some reading.

Comment: The other thing to consider is that if you build it with all the page data split sensibly you can always change the way it outputs later.